# PHP OOP accessing methods in other class

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm new to doing things the oop way. Here's what I got.

First I've made a class that connects me to my database. Then I made a class to fetch the results from the database.

`/engine/classes.php`

```
class DB
{
    public static function dbConnect() 
    {
        $db = new mysqli(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
        if ($db->connect_error) {
        die('A connection to the database cannot be made.');
        }
    }
}

class Blog
{
    public function fetchBlog() 
    {
        DB::dbConnect();
        $results = array();
        if ($blog = $db->query('SELECT * FROM blog')) {
            if ($blog->num_rows) {
                 while ($row = $blog->fetch_object()) {
                     $results[] = $row;
                 }
             $blog->free();
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Then I have a `core.php` file where I include my `classes.php` file and instantiate these classes. Like so

`/engine/core.php`

```
require_once 'classes.php';

$con = new DB();
$con->dbConnect();

$blog = new Blog();
```

Then finally I have my `index.php` where the I'd like to echo the results I get. That looks like this

index.php

```
<?php include 'engine/core.php'; ?>
html stuff
<div id="blog">
    <?php
    $blog->fetchBlog();
    if (!count($results)) {
        echo'There are no blog posts at this time.';
    } else {
        foreach ($results as $r) { 
            echo'<div class="blogPost">
                <em>', escape($r->postDate), '</em>
                <h1>', escape($r->postTitle), '</h1>
                <div>', escape($r->postBody), '</div>
            </div>';
        } 
    }

    ?>
</div>
```

I do have error reporting on and do not get errors on `core.php` or `classes.php`. However on my `index.php` page I am getting these errors

```
Notice: Undefined variable: db in C:\wamp\www\website\engine\classes.php on line 138
 Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\website\engine\classes.php on line 138
```

How can I correct this? I assume I need a __construct somewhere in there and I also assume I'm not calling the `dbConnect` method correctly. I have tried a lot of things but listing them here would just be too much? Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Pass the database dependency inside the constructor of your `Blog` class to make it locally accessible.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your `$db` variable is local to the `DB::dbConnect()` function, which means once that function is done running it is destroyed.

There's also an issue with the `$results` where you didn't return it from the function or assign a value from the function call.

With the following edits you will be able to make it work, I'll comment it to hopefully allow you to better understand why I've done things the way I did.

> /engine/classes.php

```
class DB
{
    /**
     * keep the variable available for all instances of the DB class since it's static.
     */ 
    static protected $db;

    /**
     * get database instance, connect if necessary
     */
    public static function conn()
    {
        /**
         * automatically connect to the database if it's not connected
         * this is known as lazy loading, which means it only creates
         * the resource at the exact time that it needs it
         */
        if (false === (self::$db instanceof mysqli) {
            self::connect();
        }
        return self::$db;
    }

    /**
     * create a connection to the database
     */
    protected static function connect() 
    {
        self::$db = new mysqli(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
        if (self::$db->connect_error) {
            die('A connection to the database cannot be made.');
        }
    }
}

class Blog
{
    public function fetchBlog() 
    {
        $results = array();
        /**
         * Since the db method is static, you can just call it without an instance
         */
        if ($blog = DB::conn()->query('SELECT * FROM blog')) {
            if ($blog->num_rows) {
                 while ($row = $blog->fetch_object()) {
                     $results[] = $row;
                 }
             $blog->free();
             }
         }
     /**
      * you didn't do anything with the results, presumably you want to return them so you can do something with them
      */
     return $results;
     }

}
```

> /engine/core.php

```
require_once 'classes.php';

/**
 * It is unnecessary to create an instance of the DB class
 * as all methods are defined statically
 */
//$con = new DB();
//$con->dbConnect();

$blog = new Blog();
```

> index.php

```
<?php include 'engine/core.php'; ?>
<!-- html stuff -->
<div id="blog">
    <?php
    /**
     * You must assign the output of the function call so you can make use of it
     */
    $results = $blog->fetchBlog();
    if (!count($results)) {
        echo'There are no blog posts at this time.';
    } else {
        foreach ($results as $r) { 
            echo'<div class="blogPost">
                <em>', escape($r->postDate), '</em>
                <h1>', escape($r->postTitle), '</h1>
                <div>', escape($r->postBody), '</div>
            </div>';
        } 
    }

    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried it out and now Im getting this error Constructor DB::db() cannot be static in C:\wamp\www\ballpointmachinist\engine\classes.php on line 36 I also added a ) to the if statement inside the db method.

Comment: So I found out that method and class name cannot match. so I changed it but now I have a unexpected ruturn refrencing the return $results

Comment: I figured it out return need to be inside the method. Thanks for the help Augwa and Avinash

Comment: sorry about that @user3770278 I didn't have those correct, it's updated now, glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

In your class `Blog` you just access a variable `$db` that is never declared in the line:

```
if ($blog = $db->query('SELECT * FROM blog')) {
```

You would have to add a variable `$db` to your class DB and then create a new instance of that class in your class `Blog`.

Comment: $db is in DB class and I call it with DB::dbConnect in fetchBog is that wrong? Would I have to add to DB class public $db and tehn do a __construct that has something like $this->db = $db = new mysqli?

Comment: Yes, in your script above the variable `$db` is local to your `DB` class. That's why it gives an error when you are trying to call it: for the scope you are in (the `fetchBlog` function) `$db` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

In you line `if ($blog = $db->query('SELECT * FROM blog')) {`, `$db` is never declared.

What you need to do is to return `DB` object from constructor, so your class `DB` should look like below:

```
class DB
{
    public static function dbConnect() 
    {
        $db = new mysqli(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
        if ($db->connect_error) {
            die('A connection to the database cannot be made.');
        }

        // Note this line :)
        return $db;

    }
}
```

Apart from this there are lot many improvements, that can be done in your code. Just to start with I would suggest you to dive into OOP in detail from here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Off topic but I would like to add few more suggestions. As you have created your DB object creation method as a static. I would suggest to implement `Singleton` design pattern for such objects because you will need only and only one object of this class across your application. [Read More](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/design-patterns-the-singleton-pattern--cms-23073).